# fish shell: Is it possible to conveniently strip extensions?

Tags: fish

Is there any convenient way to strip an arbitrary extension from a file name, something à la bash `${i%%.*}`? Do I stick to my friend `sed`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nope. fish has a much smaller feature set than bash, relying on external commands:

```
$ set filename foo.bar.baz
$ set rootname (echo $filename | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')
$ echo $rootname
foo.bar
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. Good you posted the workaround :)

Comment: As mentioned below you can achieve the same result without external commands by using fish' `string` command.

Comment: Careful as the sed regex doesn't handle special cases, ex:
`/this/is.another/test` gives `/this/is`

Answer (score 26):

If you know the extension (eg _bak, a common usecase) this is possibly more convenient:

```bash
    for f in (ls *_bak)
        mv $f (basename $f _bak)
    end
```

Comment: This does more than strip the extension: It also strips the dirname.

Answer (score 23):

**--- Update 2022-08-02 ---**

As of fish 3.5+, there is a `path` command ([docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/path.html)) which was designed to handle stripping extensions:

```fish
$ touch test.txt.bak
$ path change-extension '' ./test.txt.bak
test.txt
```

You can also strip a set number of extensions:

```fish
set --local file ./test.txt.1.2.3
for i in (seq 3)
   set file (path change-extension '' $file)
end
echo $file
# ./test.txt
```

Or strip all extensions:

```fish
set --local file ./test.txt.1.2.3
while path extension $file
    set file (path change-extension '' $file)
end
echo $file
# ./test
```

---

***--- Original answer ---***

The fish `string` command is still the canonical way to handle this. It has some really nice sub commands that haven't been shown in other answers yet.

`split` lets you split from the right with a max of 1, so that you just get the last extension.

```fish
for f in *
    echo (string split -m1 -r '.' "$f")[1]
end
```

`replace` lets you use a regex to lop off the extension, defined as the final dot to the end of the string

```fish
for f in *
    string replace -r '\.[^\.]*$' '' "$f"
end
```

`man string` for more info and some great examples.

**Update:**

If your system has proper `basename` and `dirname` utilities, you can use something like this:

```fish
function stripext \
    --description "strip file extension"
    
    for arg in $argv
        echo (dirname $arg)/(string replace -r '\.[^\.]+$' '' (basename $arg))
    end
end
```

Comment: Careful as this removes anything after the last dot on filename with no ext, ex: `/this/is.another/test` gives `/this/is`

Comment: @NinjaInc - this is why I'm pretty excited to finally see the `path` utility make it's way into Fish: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/pull/8265

Comment: I am not here to say anything bad about fish, since I also use it as my default shell... but sometimes bash is much simpler.... `bash -c for a in *.txt; do mv $a ${a%.*}.json; done`

Comment: @fsan - bash may be more terse, but I don't agree that it's simpler. If you don't remember that `%.*` strips an extension, discovering that is a pain compared to fish's `help path`. And what if your files had spaces? Will bash's word splitting burn you because you didn't quote it? The fish version of your example isn't that much different, but is arguably better in nearly every respect `for f in *.txt; mv $f (path change-extension 'json' $f); end`.

Answer (score 11):

You can strip off the extension from a filename using the [string](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string) command:

```
echo (string split -r -m1 . $filename)[1]
```

This will split `filename` at the right-most dot and print the first element of the resulting list. If there is no dot, that list will contain a single element with `filename`.

If you also need to strip off leading directories, combine it with basename:

```
echo (basename $filename | string split -r -m1 .)[1]
```

In this example, `string` reads its input from stdin rather than being passed the filename as a command line argument.

Comment: You can also use the option `--field` (`-f`) to select the first field instead of using `[1]`. Example: `string split --right --max 1 --field 1 . $filename`; Also I don't think you need `echo` because `string split` will print the output already.

Comment: Careful as this splits at the last dot of a filepath when a filename has no ext, ex: `/this/is.another/test` gives `/this/is`

Answer (score 4):

With the `string match` function built into fish you can do

```bash
set rootname (string match -r "(.*)\.[^\.]*\$" $filename)[2]
```

The string match returns a list of 2 items. The first is the whole string, and the second one is the first regexp match (the stuff inside the parentheses in the regex). So, we grab the second one with the [2].

Comment: Careful as this removes anything after the last dot on filename with no ext, ex: `/this/is.another/test` gives `/this/is`

Answer (score -2):

I too need a function to split random files root and extension. Rather than re-implementing naively the feature at the risk of meeting caveats (ex: dot before separator), I am forwarding the task to Python's built-in [POSIX path](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/66c5853406bbcccecf35372795078c0641a5f385/Lib/genericpath.py#L121) libraries and inherit from their expertise.

Here is an humble example of what one may prefer:

```sh
function splitext --description "Print filepath(s) root, stem or extension"

    argparse 'e/ext' 's/stem' -- $argv

    for arg in $argv
        if set -q _flag_ext
            set cmd 'import os' \
                    "_, ext = os.path.splitext('$arg')" \
                    'print(ext)'
        else if set -q _flag_stem
            set cmd 'from pathlib import Path' \
                    "p = Path('$arg')" \
                    'print(p.stem)'
        else
            set cmd 'import os' \
                    "root, _ = os.path.splitext('$arg')" \
                    'print(root)'
        end
        python3 -c (string join ';' $cmd)
    end

end
```

Examples:

```sh
$ splitext /this/is.a/test.path
/this/is.a/test
$ splitext --ext /this/is.a/test.path
.path
$ splitext --stem /this/is.a/test.path
test
$ splitext /this/is.another/test
/this/is.another/test
```